# Storage recommendations for DPM 2016

Tags: raid, storage, scdpm

I am looking for deploying DPM 2016 and want to use StarWind VTL for tape backups like described in this [blog:](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/starwind-virtual-tape-library-vtl-with-microsoft-system-center-data-protection-manager)

The problem is that I do not know what storage would be best for DPM 2016.

My backup server has PERC H330 controller with 6x2TB 7.2K SAS disks and 4X800GB SSDs.
Basically, I have several options: configure RAID5, RAID6 or Storage Spaces with tiering, like it was proposed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3cf976a-e97f-402f-af2b-03da0ad887e0/how-to-configure-dpm-2016-storage?forum=dataprotectionmanager). I searched a lot for advice but want to know more thoughts and arguments for the best solution.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can absolutely build tiered Storage Spaces with your spinners + flash! In this case hot backups will stay on-site within fastest possible tier (flash initially, offloaded to disks after flash filled with data 100% <- this process is controlled by Windows Storage Spaces' mechanism), and cold backups will find their way to off-site public cloud after threshold value & conditions met <- this one is controller by VTL itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I found here that Storage Spaces not supported in DPM: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554221(v=sc.12).aspx Am I correct that I can do just disk to tape backups with StarWind VTL or I have to do disk to disk before? If so, what RAID would be better to use?

Comment: You don’t deal with Storage Spaces within this scenario, you rather make DPM “talk” to VTL APIs: It’s irrelevant for DPM what’s behind tape.

Comment: Because tape (in this case - virtual) does only streaming writes, you can use RAID6 or double  parity Storage Spaces: Either way there will be no so-called “write hole”.